# Maven phase/goal precedence issue

Tags: build-automation, filtering, maven-3

I have some properties in two bash scripts I want substituted when running `mvn test`, such that one script might be executed before the `test` phase, and one after, using the `exec-maven-plugin`.

The bash scripts look like so:

**startMongo**

```
#!/bin/bash

${mongodNixDirLocation}/mongod --fork --logpath "${mongodLogDir}" --port ${mongodbTestPort}

/bin/sleep 10
```

**stopMongo**

```
#!/bin/bash

mongoDbServer=`lsof -i tcp:${mongodbTestPort}| awk 'NR!=1 {print $2}'`

for i in $mongoDbServer; do
    echo "Stopping mongo DB server instance: $i"
    kill -s SIGINT $i
done
```

I seem to be having issues with the order of execution when I run `mvn test`. The output is like [so](http://pastebin.com/LjaRWa1k).

The `exec-maven-plugin` is trying to execute the `startMongo` script before the proper substitutions have been made - hence the error message appearing to execute `mongod` from `/mongod`.

If I run `mvn process-test-resources`, the substitutions are correctly made, and I can manually run the script successfully.

My pom.xml is configured like [so](http://pastebin.com/GdxkkEvx). How can I appropriately configure the correct phases such that this will work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem is in the following line:

```
<executable>src/test/resources/startMongo</executable>
```

If this script - `startMango` - needs filtering, the filtering will be done and the result places in `target/test-classes` folder.  The original file will not be updated.

How about altering the above line as:

```
<executable>${project.build.directory}/test-classes/startMongo</executable>
```

Likewise for `stopMongo` as well.

I am not sure how it manually worked though.